# How to get public IP addresses of all nodes in an Amazon EC2 cluster?

Tags: command-line, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudera

## Setup:

I am able to spin-off an Amazon EC2 cluster with 5 nodes. Now I have to install some package on it. I have written a script which takes list of IP addresses and installs that package on those machines. The script to install the package is ready and working.

## Problem:

Right now I am creating the list of IP address manually, like going to the Amazon Management Console and click on each node and get the Public DNS Name/IP (duh!). I would like to automate this part as soon I will need to spin-off clusters of few hundred nodes and manually retrieving 100s IP address is painful.

So in short, is there a way by which I can get public IP address of all the nodes in my cluster? Some command-line script would be ideal I guess.

Comment: Down-voter, care to leave a comment at least?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should probably use [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress" --output text
```

This should give you a list of public IPs.